# Hierarchy data display using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, hierarchical-data, master-detail

I have an application where I need to display hierarchical data based on data selection (parent-child). The hierarchy is:

Company > Work Sector > Sector Division > Division head > Employees Reporting

By design, each of the above items is represented using a combobox. Each level below will get populated based on the selection above. For example, selecting a company will load all the work sectors in the company. Selecting a work sector will load all the divisions and so on.

Is it possible to accomplish this by just writing XAML (using DataContext or anything else)? I really dont want to write the SelectionChanged event for each combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is [Master-Detail Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#master_detail_scenario).

Especially [How to: Use the Master-Detail Pattern with Hierarchical Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742531.aspx)